# Definition of Right Lexicographical Ordering

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I have a quick question on what's called the right lexicographical ordering: the text I'm reading defines it as follows ($s \prec t$ means $s$ is an initial segment of $t$):

> Consider $\omega^{<\omega}$ and define the right lexicographical ordering $<_r$ as follows: for finite strings $s,t$ we set $s <_r t$ iff $t \prec s$ or, if that fails, $s(i) < t(i)$ where $i$ is the least index at which $s$ and $t$ differ.

This definition seems very unintuitive to me. In particular, what does the term "right" refer to here? It is clear that the empty string is $<_r$-maximal. Further, the ordering says that the shorter the string, the greater it is w.r.t. $<_r$. And if two strings disagree somewhere, then the string with the smaller value at the disagreement is considered smaller w.r.t. $<_r$. This last point doesn't make sense to me intuitively.

Edit: Now with William's comment I am wondering: is this actually the reverse dictionary order? I don't think it is as (as mentioned in my comment) in the usual dictionary order we have $\langle 0,1,2 \rangle < \langle 0,1,3 \rangle$, but we also have $\langle 0,1,2 \rangle <_r \langle 0,1,3 \rangle$. Is there a typo somewhere, or am I just misunderstanding the ordering?

Comment: It is the reverse order of the dictionary order.

Comment: @WilliamElliot But in the dictionary order $\langle 0,1,2 \rangle < \langle 0,1,3 \rangle$, just as under $<_r$.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: It's not "reverse lexicographic order", it's "right lexicographic order".

Comment: In the usual lexicographic order, an initial segment is smaller than the word (as in a dictionary, where "order" would go before "ordering". It would seem that here you keeping lexicographic order, but you are putting longer words first. This is not the reverse lexicographic order. I have not encountered this particular order before, but I would guess that it is "right" because the "rightmost word" goes first when there is a tie: longer word beats shorter word.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Is this a standard ordering? Or is it still possible that there is a typo in the definition? (by "standard" I mean well-known)

Comment: @MacRance: I don't usually work with orders, so I don't know how standard it might be; the fact that they include "right" suggests that they do not mean the standard lexicographic order, which is usually just called "lexicographic order"; nor the reverse lexicographic order. As I said, I have not encountered it before, but that does not necessarily mean anything.